# how to install ubuntu with usb drive?

Tags: installation

I have windows 7.

I downloaded ubuntu but don't know how to boot through usb drive.

There is no startup disk creator in windows 7.

Please give a suitable solution

Answer (score 3):

The esiest way is described in official Ubuntu website.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

You can also use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.net/) in Windows 7.